# JS code below works for one <div> and doesn't work for another

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
$("#mainPageSlideShow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('#mainPageSlideShow > div:first')
      .fadeOut(1000)
      .next()
      .fadeIn(1000)
      .end()
      .appendTo('#mainPageSlideShow');
}, 3000);
```

Comment: how many #mainPageSlideShow > div:first do you think you have in your page?

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: <div id="mainPageSlideShow">
                            <div>
                                <img src="#" class="img-rounded" alt="Compare Province by Clicking Here" style="width:100%; height: 400px" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <img src="#" class="img-rounded" alt="Compare Province by Clicking Here" style="width:100%; height: 400px" />
                            </div>
                            </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `div:visible` instead of `div:first` and for the better effect maybe change your code to fade in next div when current is totally hidden? Code below:

```
$("#mainPageSlideShow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('#mainPageSlideShow > div:visible')
    .fadeOut(1000, function () {
        $(this).next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#mainPageSlideShow');
    });
}, 3000);
```